# libv8_snapshot.a: No such file or directory

Tags: v8, gyp

downloaded code as described in [Using Git](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Using%20Git):

```
fetch v8
cd v8
```

built as described in [BuildingWithGYP](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Building%20with%20Gyp):

```
gclient sync
make x64.release
```

updated to the latest master, and used a sample:

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

but when building a samle as described in [Get Started](https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started), I met an error

```
g++ -I. hello_world.cc -o hello_world -Wl,--start-group out/x64.release/obj.target/{tools/gyp/libv8_{base,libbase,snapshot,libplatform},third_party/icu/libicu{uc,i18n,data}}.a -Wl,--end-group -lrt -pthread -std=c++0x

g++: error: out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_snapshot.a: No such file or directory
```

and it turns out there is no such file:

```
$ find . -name *snapshot*.a
./out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_nosnapshot.a
./out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_external_snapshot.a
```

So the question is, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: BTW, the platform is Ubuntu 14.04, x86_64

Answer (score 0):

it seems it is because the unstable version.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/v8-users/SBAGmGr7eBg

according this link above:

> "Getting Started is only compatible with the current Stable version. I am currently updating it to be compatible with version 4.4."

so we can checkout the stable version like 4.4

```
git checkout -b 4.4 -t branch-heads/4.4
```

then continue the rest of steps.

but noticed the hello-world.cc exist in version 4.5, so we can download the example first.

here are the steps I copied from the link:

> `Goto v8/
>   git checkout -b 4.5 -t branch-heads/4.5
>   Copy samples/hello-world.cc to v8/
>   git checkout -b 4.4 -t branch-heads/4.4
>   gclient sync
>   make x64.release snapshot=off
>   g++ -I. hello-world.cc -o hello_world -Wl,--start-group out/x64.release/obj.target/{tools/gyp/libv8_{base,libbase,nosnapshot,libplatform},third_party/icu/libicu{uc,i18n,data}}.a -Wl,--end-group -lrt -ldl -pthread -std=c++0x
>   ./hello_world`